# #define as function argument in C

Tags: c

Durning making higher level layer I've got a situation when I need to pass predefined arguments to a function. Is there any other way than using switch in this case?

```
# define    SEEK_SET    0

static _move_pos(FILE *file, long int pos, uint8_t SEEK_);

switch(SEEK_){
    case 0:
        if((err = fseek(file, pos, SEEK_SET)) != 0) {
            return err;
        }
        break;
    case 1:
        if((err = fseek(file, pos, SEEK_CUR)) != 0) {
            return err;
        }
        break;
    case 2:
        if((err = fseek(file, pos, SEEK_END)) != 0) {
            return err;
        }
        break;
}
```

Comment: Can't you pass `SEEK_` directly as an argument? Then no `switch` is needed. Note that `SEEK_SET` is already defined in `stdio.h`

Comment: static _move_pos(FILE *file, long int pos, uint8_t SEEK_); - I'm calling function like this and than switch is making the job for me... I'm asking for elegant way to use defines.

Comment: If you call it as `move_pos(myfile, mypos, SEEK_SET)`  and then no `#define` or `switch` is needed. Are you over-thinking this? It's not clear why you need a function at all, and not just call `fseek()` directly.

Comment: you may be right it seems there is nothing to handle as unexpected error... anyway things like this give me questions i would like to have the answer to

Comment: Please show a [mcve]. The code snippet you posted is really weird. This looks like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). What are you _actually_ trying to achieve?

Comment: You repeat a lot of code. Why don't just use the switch/case for setting `SEEK_SET`, `SEEK_CUR` etc. based on the value of `SEEK_`?

Comment: an `enum` perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any other way than using switch in this case?

Use multiple `if`s instead of `switch`.

Just pass the argument along and let the user pass the proper argument.

```
void _move_pos(FILE *file, long int pos, uint8_t SEEK_) {
     fseek(file, pos, SEEK_);
}
```

Use a map or a lookup table or a dispatch table.

```
void _move_pos(FILE *file, long int pos, uint8_t SEEK_) {
     static int arg[3] = {
        [0] = SEEK_SET,
        [1] = SEEK_CUR,
        [2] = SEEK_END,
     };
     fseek(file, pos, arg[SEEK_]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use function pointers.

```
int s0(FILE *stream, off_t offset) { return fseek(stream, offset, SEEK_SET); }
int s1(FILE *stream, off_t offset) { return fseek(stream, offset, SEEK_CUR); }
int s2(FILE *stream, off_t offset) { return fseek(stream, offset, SEEK_END); }

typedef int (*fptr_t)(FILE *, off_t);

/* It is UB to call _move_pos with something other than 0, 1, or 2 for argument SEEK_ */
int _move_pos(FILE *file, long int pos, uint8_t SEEK_) {
    static fptr_t fp[3] = {s0, s1, s2};
    int err = fp[SEEK_](file, pos);
    if (err != ESP_OK) return err;
    return 0;
}
```